# Filter table with multiple radio inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablefilter

All I want is filter the table with radio inputs.
This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eNLWn/)

I am using this inputs and table:

```
<div style="border:1px solid;">
<input  type="radio" id="Bob" name="name"  />Bob
<input type="radio" id="Jay" name="name"  />Jay
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid; margin:5px 0;">
<input type="radio" id="developer" name="position" />Developer
<input type="radio" id="itManager" name="position" />Manager
</div>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Position</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td><td>Developer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jay</td><td>Manager</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td><td>Manager</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jay</td><td>Developer</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this js:

```
 $('#Bob').change( function() {
     $('tr').show();
     $('tr:not(:has(th)):not(:contains("Bob"))').hide();
 });

 $('#Jay').change( function() {
     $('tr').show();
     $('tr:not(:has(th)):not(:contains("Jay"))').hide();
 });

 $('#developer').change( function() {
     $('tr').show();
     $('tr:not(:has(th)):not(:contains("Developer"))').hide();
 });

 $('#itManager').change( function() {
     $('tr').show();
     $('tr:not(:has(th)):not(:contains("Manager"))').hide();
 });
```

All I need is double filter, when I select Bob, its shows only bobs than when I select Developer  I want to see Bob - Developer tr.

I know js code is wrong but I wanted you make understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, more simple:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var name = $('input[name="name"]:checked').prop('id') || '';
    var position = $('input[name="position"]:checked').prop('id') || '';
    $('tr').hide();
    $('tr:contains(' + name + ')').show();
    $('tr').not(':contains(' + position + ')').hide();
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JJpec/)

The only change in the HTML you need is to have the ID of the position radio buttons to be the same as the table. The that information can be used in the `tr` show/hide. Like:

```
<input type="radio" id="Developer" name="position" />Developer
<input type="radio" id="Manager" name="position" />Manager
```