# Javascript/Jquery: Filter a table with multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to filter a simple `HTML` table with the filter being determined by multiple radio buttons. The goal is to show/hide any rows that contain/don't contain the words in the filter.

For example if I select "**yes**" on the "`auto`" filter and "**no**" on the "manually" filter it should look in the column named "auto" for the "yes" value and on the "manually" column for the "no" value.

I tried it with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420792/filter-table-with-multiple-radio-inputs) but it filters with the logical OR and not the logical AND. Also i don't quite know how to set the filter inactive when the user wants to deactivate the according filter.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
    <label>Auto:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="auto" value="yes" />
    <label>yes</label>

    <input type="radio" name="auto" value="no" />
    <label>no</label>

    <input type="radio" name="auto" value="inactive" />
    <label>inactive</label>
    <br>

    <label>Manually:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="manually" value="yes" />
    <label>yes</label>

    <input type="radio" name="manually" value="no" />
    <label>no</label>

    <input type="radio" name="manually" value="inactive" />
    <label>inactive</label>
    <br>

    <label>Downgrade:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="downgrade" value="yes" />
    <label>yes</label>

    <input type="radio" name="downgrade" value="no" />
    <label>no</label>

    <input type="radio" name="downgrade" value="inactive" />
    <label>inactive</label>
    <br>

</form>

<table border="1" id="ExampleTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>auto</th>
        <th>manually</th>
        <th>downgrade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name1</td>
        <td class="auto">yes</td>
        <td class="manually">yes</td>
        <td class="downgrade">yes</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name2</td>
        <td class="auto">no</td>
        <td class="manually">no</td>
        <td class="downgrade">yes</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name3</td>
        <td class="auto">no</td>
        <td class="manually">yes</td>
        <td class="downgrade">no</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name4</td>
        <td class="auto">yes</td>
        <td class="manually">no</td>
        <td class="downgrade">yes</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Javascript i did with the help of the previous mentioned question:

```
<script>
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        var firstRow = 'name';
        var auto = $('input[name="auto"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        var manually = $('input[name="manually"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        var downgrade = $('input[name="downgrade"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        $('tr').hide();
        $('tr:contains(' + firstRow + ')').show();
        $('tr:contains(' + auto + ')').show();
        $('tr').not(':contains(' + manually + ')').hide();
        $('tr').not(':contains(' + downgrade + ')').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Here is also an image for better understanding:

[image: project_image]

Since i usually don't use JS and JQuery I couldn't quite figure out the problem and the time is short. I would be very grateful for a push in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: In which order you want to apply AND logic ?

Comment: I thought, it shouldn't matter in which order the AND applies since the rows have to contain all the requirements in the filter? I only want to use the AND operator and not a mix between AND and OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think this is what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        var firstRow = 'name';
        var auto = $('input[name="auto"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        var manually = $('input[name="manually"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        var downgrade = $('input[name="downgrade"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        
        var trs = $('tr:not(:first)');
        $(trs).hide();
        
        if(auto == 'inactive' || manually == 'inactive' || downgrade == 'inactive'){
          // Do nothing as any of three condition says show all
          // And currently we all rows selected in trs
        } else {
          if(auto != '' && auto != 'inactive'){
              var chkdName = $('input[name="auto"]:checked').prop('name');
              trs = $(trs).find("."+chkdName+':contains('+auto+')').parent();
          }
  
          if(manually != '' && manually != 'inactive'){
              var chkdName = $('input[name="manually"]:checked').prop('name');
              trs = $(trs).find("."+chkdName+':contains('+manually+')').parent();
          }
  
          if(downgrade != '' && downgrade != 'inactive'){
              var chkdName = $('input[name="downgrade"]:checked').prop('name');
              trs = $(trs).find("."+chkdName+':contains('+downgrade+')').parent();
          }
        }
        $(trs).show();
    });
    
    $("#reset").on('click', function(){
      $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
      $('tr').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
  <label>Auto:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="auto" value="yes" />
  <label>Yes</label>

  <input type="radio" name="auto" value="no" />
  <label>No</label>

  <input type="radio" name="auto" value="inactive" />
  <label>All</label>
  <br>

  <label>Manually:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="manually" value="yes" />
  <label>Yes</label>

  <input type="radio" name="manually" value="no" />
  <label>No</label>

  <input type="radio" name="manually" value="inactive" />
  <label>All</label>
  <br>

  <label>Downgrade:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="downgrade" value="yes" />
  <label>Yes</label>

  <input type="radio" name="downgrade" value="no" />
  <label>No</label>

  <input type="radio" name="downgrade" value="inactive" />
  <label>All</label>
  <br>
</form>
<br><button id="reset">Reset</button><br><br><br><br>
<table border="1" id="ExampleTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Auto</th>
      <th>Manually</th>
      <th>Downgrade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name1</td>
      <td class="auto">no</td>
      <td class="manually">no</td>
      <td class="downgrade">no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name2</td>
      <td class="auto">no</td>
      <td class="manually">no</td>
      <td class="downgrade">yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name3</td>
      <td class="auto">no</td>
      <td class="manually">yes</td>
      <td class="downgrade">no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name4</td>
      <td class="auto">yes</td>
      <td class="manually">no</td>
      <td class="downgrade">no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name5</td>
      <td class="auto">yes</td>
      <td class="manually">no</td>
      <td class="downgrade">yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name6</td>
      <td class="auto">yes</td>
      <td class="manually">yes</td>
      <td class="downgrade">no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name7</td>
      <td class="auto">no</td>
      <td class="manually">yes</td>
      <td class="downgrade">yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name8</td>
      <td class="auto">yes</td>
      <td class="manually">yes</td>
      <td class="downgrade">yes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the working copy: [fiddle url](https://plnkr.co/edit/PyaHur2a1wquT6t79ixX?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. I just needed to change the || in "if(auto == 'inactive' || manually == 'inactive' || downgrade == 'inactive')" to a &&. Thank you very much for your time and the answer. <3

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want to do with Inactive Radio button,

Without inactive following code will solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        var firstRow = 'name';
        var auto = $('input[name="auto"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        var manually = $('input[name="manually"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        var downgrade = $('input[name="downgrade"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
        $('tr').hide();
        $('tr:contains(' + firstRow + ')').show();

        var chks = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');

        var trs ;
        if(auto!= '' && auto != 'inactive'){
            var chkName = $('input[name="auto"]:checked').prop('name');
            trs = $("tr").find("."+chkName+':contains('+auto+')').parent();
        }

        if(manually!= '' && manually != 'inactive'){
            var chkName = $('input[name="manually"]:checked').prop('name');
            trs = $(trs).find("."+chkName+':contains('+manually+')').parent();
        }

        if(downgrade!= '' && downgrade!= 'inactive'){
            var chkName = $('input[name="downgrade"]:checked').prop('name');
            trs = $(trs).find("."+chkName+':contains('+downgrade+')').parent();
        }
        $(trs).show();

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and your time. +1

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
...
<tr class="header"> // added class here
    <th>name</th>
    <th>auto</th>
    <th>manually</th>
    <th>downgrade</th>
</tr>
...
```

**Script**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var auto = $('input[name="auto"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
    var manually = $('input[name="manually"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
    var downgrade = $('input[name="downgrade"]:checked').prop('value') || '';
    $('tr:not("[class=header]")').each(function(){
        var hide = true;
        if(auto) {
            hide = $(this).find('td.auto').html() != auto;
        }
        if(manually && !hide) {
            hide = $(this).find('td.manually').html() != manually;
        }
        if(downgrade && !hide) {
            hide = hide && $(this).find('td.downgrade').html() != downgrade;
        }

        if(hide) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: For your information i didn't downvote your answer since i don't have enough reputation and am grateful for every answer and the time taken to evaluate my question. I am trying to figure out on my own with the filter logic but like written in the question above, I need a push in the right direction since i don't usually work with JS or Jquery.

Comment: @M.Anderson no worries, someone who didn't like downvoted it. The main thing your problem should be resolved. I think this solution will give you a direction so that you can achieve whatever you want. In this solution it's `AND` condition you play with it.

Comment: @M.Anderson I have updated the answer did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a big push in the right direction, thank you

Comment: @M.Anderson happy to hear that, you can also accept the answer.